# TypeORM Query Builder Returning Empty Array When Raw SQL Works

Tags: postgresql, typescript, typeorm

I'm attempting to run the following type of query using `createQueryBuilder`. I've verified that all of my entities are properly created and joined. However, running the following returns an empty array:

```
let apiKey = await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .from(ApiKey, "apiKey")
    .innerJoinAndSelect("apiKey.site", "site")
    .where("site.domain = :domain", { domain: "mysitename.com" })
    .andWhere("apiKey.key = :key", { key })
    .getMany()
```

But! When I replace `getMany()` with `getSql()`, copy the raw SQL and run it, it works! I get the result I expected:

```
SELECT "site"."id" AS "site_id", "site"."domain" AS "site_domain", "site"."name" AS "site_name", "site"."createdAt" AS "site_createdAt", "site"."apiKeyId" AS "site_apiKeyId", "site"."userId" AS "site_userId" FROM "api_key" "apiKey" INNER JOIN "site" "site" ON "site"."id"="apiKey"."siteId" WHERE "site"."domain" = 'mysitename.com'
```

Is there any thing obviously wrong with how I'm trying to build this query?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

.getMany() returns type Promise of Entity[], and given the nature of your query, I suspect you are not returning an entity at all. Try .getRawMany() or .getRawAndEntities()

See the [documentation on QueryBuilder here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-values-using-querybuilder) for more details.

Comment: This worked! Do you have any resources/docs on how I'd craft that query to return an entity (or entities) instead of the raw results?

Comment: May be to some it would help, Can refer the [docs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/select-query-builder.md#getting-values-using-querybuilder) for understanding getRawMany()

Comment: Great idea @Zaker I'll update to include that reference

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the repository

```
let apiKey = await getConnection()
    .getRepository(ApiKey) // <-----------
    .createQueryBuilder('apiKey') // <-----------
    .innerJoinAndSelect("apiKey.site", "site")
    .where("site.domain = :domain", { domain: "mysitename.com" })
    .andWhere("apiKey.key = :key", { key })
    .getMany()
```